# BAT file to index folder structure to HTML

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I've never written a BAT file before, but I want to do the following.

On a shared network drive we've got a file / folder-structure. I want my colleagues to be able to double click a BAT file. The BAT file should then produce an HTML index of these files with links, and a header per folder and subfolder (no more than three levels).

I think I've gotten pretty close Googling and copying code, but I'm stuck at the header part.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd %~dp0
for /L %%n in (1 1 500) do (
if "!__cd__:~%%n,1!" neq "" set /a "len=%%n+1"
)

for /r . %%g in (*) do (
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "absPath=%%g"
  set "relPath=!absPath:~%len%!"
  for %%F in ("!absPath!") do set "var=%%~dpF"

  [MISSING CODE HERE]

  echo "<a href='http://linkhere.com/!relPath!'>%%~ng</a>" >>output.txt
  endlocal
)
echo %~dp0
popd
pause
```

It might be messy, since I'm not exactly sure what it's doing. 
This file mounts the drive, then loops through all the folders and lists them as a link. However, I need to add a header everytime the loop reaches a new folder or subfolder. This header should be HTML, so I can add functionality like expand and collapse and formatting.

I've tried it with something in this general direction

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=\" %%a in ("!relPath!") do set a=%%a&set b=%%b&set c=%%c&set d=%%d
set "fname=!d!" & set "fone=!a!" & set "ftwo=!b!" & set "fthree=!c!" & set "mainFolder=!a!"
IF [!fname!] == [] (set "fname=!c!" & set "fone=!a!" & set "ftwo=!b!" & set "fthree=")
IF [!fname!] == [] (set "fname=!b!" & set "fone=!a!" & set "ftwo=" & set "fthree=")
IF [!fname!] == [] (set "fname=!a!" & set "fone=" & set "ftwo=" & set "fthree=" & set "mainFolder=")
```

This sets every folder and filename into some variables.  I was hoping to use this to echo a header every time one of these variables change, but I can't seem to work it out.

Maybe I'm completely on the wrong track, but I'll gladly hear how it should be done.

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit > 
Foxidrive suggested I'd add in examples of the folder structure and the output.

[image: Folder structure]
The screenshot above demonstrates the folder structure. The BAT file would be located in the top folder (Called *Standaard formulieren*).

Output should be something in the form of this pseudo-HTML

```
<h2 class='header' onClick='showHide(1)'>ABU</h2>
<div id='itemlist1' class='itemlist'>
<ul>
 <li><a href='http://link-to-file.com/ABU/filename.doc'>Filename</a></li>
 <li><a href='http://link-to-file.com/ABU/filename%202.doc'>Filename 2</a></li>
</ul> 
</div>
[etc...]
<h2 class='header' onClick='showHide(9)'>Personeelszaken</h2>
<div id='itemlist9' class='itemlist'>
<h3 class='subheader' onClick='showHide(10)'>Algemeen</h2>
<div id='itemlist10' class='subitemlist'>
<ul>
 <li><a href='http://link-to-file.com/Personeelszaken/Algemeen/filename.doc'>Filename</a></li>
 <li><a href='http://link-to-file.com/Personeelszaken/Algemeen/filename%202.doc'>Filename 2</a></li>
</ul>
</div> 
</div>
[etc...]
```

Comment: Instead of reading code that doesn't work correctly, can you provide the input folder/file structure and a html file of what you need from that?  Someone may provide working code to do what you need.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll add both to the OP in a minute. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproducing your HTML is not my specialty but this should create a HTML of sorts which contains enough info to help you on your way - well I hope so.

**EDITED: to include full list of subdirectories recursively, corrected relative paths**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "basefolder=d:\Standaard formulieren"
pushd "%basefolder%"

(
for /d /r %%a in (*) do (
   pushd "%%a"
          echo going into "%%a"
    for /r %%b in (*) do (
       set "relfolder=%%a"
       set "relfolder=!relfolder:%basefolder%\=!"
       set "relfolder=!relfolder:\=/!"
       set "filename=%%~nb"
       set "filename=!filename: =%%20!"
          echo ^<li^>^<a href="http://link-to-file.com/!relfolder!/!filename!%%~xb"^>%%~nb^</a^>^</li^>
    )
   popd
   echo leaving "%%a"
)
)>"file.html"
echo done
pause
```

Comment: This is glorious, thanks! P.s. I had to replace the first pushd with `pushd %~dp0` to make it work with the network share, but this is the exact answer to my problem.

Comment: Addition: I (rightfully) accepted this answer, but it seems to glitch out on subfolders. It lists all the items, but it doesn't add the headers. It also doesn't add the subfolders to the link, so it becomes `Personeelszaken/file.doc` instead of the correct `Personeelszaken/Algemeen/file.doc`.

Comment: I altered it to include all subdirectories and insert the relative paths.  The network share may need further tweaking...  and the headers were beyond my HTML knowledge so I don't know the correct positioning of all the items.

Answer (score 0):

Foxidrive fixed the problem (so upvote him instead), but here's my modified code to work with a network share.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

pushd %~dp0

(
for /d /r %%a in (*) do (
   pushd "%%a"
   set "folder=%%a"
          echo ^<h1^>!folder:~25!^</h1^>^<ul^>
    for /r %%b in (*) do (
   set "filename=%%~nb"
   set "filename=!filename: =%%20!"
   echo ^<li^>^<a href="http://link-to-file.com/Standaard formulieren/!folder:~25!/!filename!%%~xb"^>%%~nb^</a^>^</li^>
)
 popd
 echo ^</ul^>
)
)>"file.html"
echo done
pause
```

It relies on a fixed amount of characters in the path. In my case 25 characters.