# BAT file glitch while looping through subfolders

Tags: batch-file

After asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755444/bat-file-to-index-folder-structure-to-html) on StackOverflow, I've written a .BAT-code that loops through all folders on a shared network drive, lists all files, then outputs HTML.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd %~dp0
(
echo ^<a href="javascript:toggleAll()" class='toggleAll' style="color:#f57832;" ^>Alles openen^</a^>
for /d /r %%a in (*) do (
   pushd "%%a"
   set "folder=%%a"
   echo ^<h1 onClick="showHide($(this))" class="belangrijkeheader"^>!folder:~25!^</h1^>^<ul class='belangrijkelijst'^>

    for /r %%b in (*) do (
   set "filename=%%~nb"
   set "filename=!filename: =%%20!"
   echo ^<li^>^<a href="http://someurl.com:8081/somefolder/!folder:~25!/!filename!%%~xb"^>%%~nb^</a^>^</li^>
)
 popd
 echo ^</ul^>
)
)>"file.html"
start file.html
pause
```

It works pretty well, with the exception of subfolders. Each subfolder creates two entries. So, if we had a folder `folder1` with two subfolders, `subfolder1` and `subfolder2` and both had a file, three things would be in the output

> **Folder1**
>
> fileinfolder1.jpg
>
> fileinfolder2.jpg
>
> **Folder1/subfolder1**
>
> fileinfolder1.jpg
>
> **Folder1/subfolder2**
>
> fileinfolder2.jpg

I don't want the first entry, since the links are broken, and it doesn't show in what subfolder it is. However, I don't have a clue what to edit in my .bat file to make sure only the second two are shown.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your inner loop is recursively listing all files within the current folder (including subfolders).

All you need to do is remove the /R option.

**incorrect**

```
for /r %%b in (*) do (
```

**correct**

```
for %%b in (*) do (
```

Note - You have additional potential problems.

- File names containing `!` will fail because delayed expansion will corrupt the FOR variable expansion.
- I think there are a number of url encoding issues that you have not addressed, since file names can contain `+` and `%`. There may be other issues.

Comment: Amazingly simple, thanks! I will also look at your warnings, but since it's a small, rather controlled environment, those two shouldn't be a huge problem.